# Under what conditions does convergence of DEs imply convergence of solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider a continuous time nonlinear dynamical system
$$\dot X = f(X, t), \quad X = (x_1, \dotsc, x_N),\tag{1}$$
and a particular solution $X(t)$ with initial value $X(0) = X_0$. Moreover, suppose that, for every $r > 0$, I can obtain a solution $Y_r(t)$ to the related system
$$\dot Y = f(Y, t) + \frac{1}{r} g(Y,t),\tag{2}$$
with initial value
$$Y_r(0) = X_0 + O(r^{-1}).\tag{3}$$
One would naively expect that $Y_r(t) \to X(t)$ pointwise as $r \to \infty$, but is this necessarily the case? I suspect not, but I cannot think of a counterexample. Are there some conditions on $f$ and $g$ (continuity, differentiability, ...) that would guarantee such convergence of the solutions?

I would also appreciate helpful reference suggestions and/or search terms.

Comment: You should try to use the variation of constants formula.

Comment: @JohnB I assume you mean [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)? I don't quite see how that would work, since that is a method for solution of *linear* DEs, while the DEs in my question are *nonlinear*. Also, my question is not really about obtaining solutions. But maybe you had something else in mind? Could you elaborate?

Comment: It can be used as well for nonlinear equations, the point is that you add something on the right-hand side. Sorry, I regret that I have to leave the computation for you, this would take a bit too much tome right now.

Comment: @JohnB Hmm, unfortunately I don't quite see what you are getting at. But fair enough, you are certainly under no obligation to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of Lipschitz continous $f+\tfrac{g}{r}$ and continous $g$, I was able to show the desired result. If we consider the difference between $X$ and $Y_r$ we obtain
$$
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(X-Y_r)=f(X,t)-f(Y_r,t)-\tfrac{1}{r}g(Y_r,t)\\
\Rightarrow \tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\tfrac{1}{2}|X-Y_r|^2=\left(f(X,t)+\tfrac{1}{r}g(X,t)-f(Y_r,t)-\tfrac{1}{r}g(Y_r,t)\right)\cdot(X-Y_r)-\tfrac{1}{r}g(X,t)\cdot(X-Y_r)\\
\Rightarrow \tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}|X-Y_r|^2\leq 2 L|X-Y_r|^2+\tfrac{2}{r}|g(X,t)|\cdot|X-Y_r|\\
u(t)-(O(\tfrac{1}{r}))^2\leq \int_0^t2 Lu(s)ds+\tfrac{2}{r}\int_0^t|g(X,s)|\sqrt{u(s)}ds
$$
where $u(t)=|X(s)-Y(s)|^2$. A nonlinear version of Gronwall's Lemma e.g. [here, Theorem 2.4](https://rgmia.org/papers/v6n2/youngho13-4.pdf) yields
$$
u(t)\leq e^{2Lt}\left(O(\tfrac{1}{r})+\tfrac{1}{r}\int_0^t|g(X(s),s)|e^{2Ls}ds\right)^2
$$

this proves the desired convergence.

Remark: The lipschitz continuity of $f+\tfrac{g}{r}$ can be replaced by $f$ lipschitz and $|g(y,t)|\leq C(t)$ uniformly bounded in $y$.

Comment: This looks promising! You seem to have ignored the vector nature of the original problem, but I expect the conclusion to be similar either way. Could you clarify how the final inequality proves convergence? The form of $Y(t)$ depends on $r$ (that's why I wrote it as $Y_r(t)$), so is it not possible that the integral inside the parenthesis grows faster than $r$ as $r \to \infty$?

Comment: You are completely right in both aspects, thanks for reading in so thoroughly! I'll have a look at it later today but we defintely need additional assumptions on $g$.

Comment: That is very kind of you. If you feel at all hesitant to spend time working this out (it is my problem after all) some tips about possible useful reading would also be much appreciated.

Comment: I think I fixed the mistakes, please have a look.

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply. From what I can see, this seems correct (though I'm not very familiar with Grönwall's lemma). Very nice, thank you!